# Calling Javascript function from PHP function

Tags: php, javascript, function

Below is my code in a single PHP file named `testOne.php`

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function testAlert(firstValue, secondValue)
          {
               alert ("Passed: "+firstValue+secondValue);
          }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
  ....
</body>
</html>

<?php
     function testPassedValues($One, $Two)
     {
        echo "<input type = \"button\" onclick = \"testAlert($One[2], $Two[2])\">Click Here!</input>";
     }

     $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
     if (mysql_select_db("myDatabase", $link))
     {
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE");
         while($currRowOne = mysql_fetch_row($result) &&
               $currRowTwo = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {
             testPassedValues($currRowOne, $currRowTwo);
         }
     }
?>
```

To help in understanding, I am calling a javascript method `testAlert()` from the PHP function `testPassedValues()`. However, I am not sure what the issue is since the call is not successful. In Mozilla(Firebug), I don't find any issues and in Chrome->Developer Tools, I get the error `Uncaught Syntaxerror: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in the console.

Can anyone please help me as to the root cause here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the values of `$One[2]` and `$Two[2]` are strings, so the generated HTML is:

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "testAlert(string one, string two)">Click Here!</input>
```

Which is obviously invalid javascript.

Enclose the parameters in quotes:

```
echo "<input type = \"button\" onclick = \"testAlert('$One[2]', '$Two[2]')\">Click Here!</input>";
```

You should also correctly escape the of `$One[2]` and `$Two[2]` values for HTML and JavaScript, so that you don't introduce XSS flaws or errors when a string contains an apostraphe. I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it seems to have now solved the earlier problem. But I get a new error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: testAlert is not defined`. Any suggestions on this error?

Comment: Well you're missing a closing </script> tag in the example above, maybe that is causing the issue. The error describes the problem though - the function testAlert didn't exist when the button was clicked.

Comment: Well that was my bad. I typed out the <script></script> code above and forgot to end it. However, the actual code had the ending tag and I still get the same issue

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you've fully understood where and how JavaScript and PHP are executed.

PHP is run on the server.  It generates an HTML page (potentially containing JavaScript), which is then sent to the client.  The PHP is now finished.

The client's web browser then runs the JavaScript.

To debug your JavaScript problem, take a look at the web page the client actually saw.  If Firebug is reporting a problem, that's where it is.

Comment: I did not get you when you said "take a look at the web page the client actually saw". PHP Code is updating the same page with the query results from the database. Clicking the button does not cause any change on the webpage and throws the error mentioned in Google Chrome->Developer Tools and not Firebug. Firebug does not report any error.

Comment: @darkie15: use the "view source" function in your browser.  You're not going to see any PHP there, but there is something wrong with the resulting web page.